# how to SQL query for unique values but include an extra date field?

Tags: sql, oracle

(I'm using Oracle 11.)

I have a query that looks like this to get me the unique report numbers ...

```
select distinct (REPORT_NUMBERS) from REPORTS
```

Works fine.

Now I want to sort them by their CREATION_DATE field.  I tried this ...

```
select distinct (REPORT_NUMBERS), CREATION_DATE from REPORTS order by CREATION_DATE asc
```

But I get duplicate REPORT_NUMBERS.  I tried this ...

```
select distinct (REPORT_NUMBERS) from REPORTS order by CREATION_DATE asc
```

But that gives me a "ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression" error.

How can I get the unique list of report numbers ordered by creation date?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want them ordered in an ascending way, then this should do:

```
SELECT REPORT_NUMBERS, MIN(CREATION_DATE) MinCreationDate
FROM REPORTS
GROUP BY REPORT_NUMBERS
ORDER BY MinCreationDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can GROUP to get MAX/MIN creation date:

```
select REPORT_NUMBERS, MIN(CREATION_DATE)
from REPORTS 
GROUP BY REPORT_NUMBERS
```

Min() would be the earliest date, MAX() the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement doesn't make sense, unless you want to order them by the **latest** creation date, or **earliest** creation date etc. in which case you can:

```
select REPORT_NUMBERS, MAX(CREATION_DATE) lastest_creation_date
from REPORTS
group by REPORT_NUMBERS
order by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting unique of distinct (REPORT_NUMBERS) and CREATION_DATE together.Not REPORT_NUMBERS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try following -

```
select REPORT_NUMBERS, MIN(CREATION_DATE) AS MinCreationDate
from REPORTS
group by REPORT_NUMBERS
order by 2 desc
```